# Hive Query handling of String to Int

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

```
Empid    EmpName    Grade    Salary
1        Sita       C1      20000
2        Raman      C1      30000
3        Prabhu     C2      40000
4        Anil       C2      50000
5        Abhi       C1      25000
6        Deva       C2      45000
```

I need to get the maximum grade and his corresponding salary.
How do i identify the `max` grade?

Comment: What does the title mean?

Comment: I am new to stackoverlow.So i just gave like that.I will change now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple method uses `order by` and limit`:

```
select t.*
from t
order by grade desc
limit 1;
```

If you want all values in the case of ties:

```
select t.*
from t join
     (select max(grade) from max_grade from t) tt
     on t.grade = tt. max_grade;
```